# Bootstrap 3 nested Accordion not working correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I have a nested accordion but the nested ones inside the second and third accordions do not behave like the one inside the first one.

[Bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/sBp0h03paJ)

I believe the id's all match correctly...

I actually may need a THIRD level accordion inside the second level. Can that be done, too?

Comment: each heading should have unique id. change ids for 2nd and 3rd accordion as nested2 and nested3 respectively and it will work.
Check this: http://www.bootply.com/QXQCs2OeFI

Comment: Nope, all that did was make the first one act like the other ones.

Comment: if one sub menu is open, the others should be closed. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It didn't work initially but now does, I guess I copied something wrong. Post as answer, please

Comment: Would this support a third level?

Comment: @Sumit, were you going to post as an answer?

Comment: I wasn't sure about that. I just did that and it worked. So I might not write a very good answer to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you have added the same id="nested" for more than one accordion. The id should be unique.

Also, you can have as many levels as you want. Here is an example with three levels accordion.

https://jsbin.com/sosatirusi/edit?html,output